# Shutdown cause -112

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, shutdown

My 2013 rMBP regularly freezes (screen stays on but freezes as well). I have Yosemite 10.10.1. I couldn't see such behavior in 10.9 and I don't think it's a hardware issue (had the machine serviced and an Apple Hardware Test was performed, no issues found).

In the console I found the "Previous shutdown cause: -112".
Now, I found various lists and also a [header file](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/CarbonHeaders/CarbonHeaders-18.1/MacErrors.h) where this error code occurs but it probably is not connected to this issue.

Anybody has any clues regarding this problem? It happens at least once a week. Thankfully most data is preserved after the restart, but it is worrisome anyway.

Comment: fwiw, since installing the Yosemite upgrade on my MBP, I have been getting regular kernel panics (hard crash) while debugging within XCode and stepping through code. New one on me, happens quite often ... in my case, the coreaudiod process freaks out. As for you, this MBP has been checked and declared healthy. This has been reported to Apple.

Comment: Not really a definitive answer so I'm making this a comment.  When training at Apple I asked, and have subsequently asked friends at Apple, about the shutdown cause codes.  There are no references for them but the general rule of thumb that AppleCare / Apple training follows is that positive numbers are results of users / software initiating a shutdown and negative numbers are the result of an unexpected shutdown.  A Mac that overheats will show a negative number, if you pull the power cord it will show a negative number, if a program tells it to shutdown it will show a positive number.

Comment: Usually -112 and -128 shutdown causes are hardware related. See http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/145662/ as well

Answer (score 2):

We have a small group of 2012 and 2013 retina MBP and only one in the group has the -112 restart cause logged when it freezes in a hard manner. The rest have never once froze hard or shut down/rebooted spontaneously.

No diagnostics from Apple show a specific failure - the SSD has been tested extensively and doesn't have any other errors that fsck lists or corrects (other than the typical minor and correctable filesystem corruption that a hard reboot causes).

In the last 3 months, it has logged two -112 restarts and two -128 restarts.

If you paid for AppleCare - take it in and get it repaired. If you have to pay for a repair, it will likely be the $300 to $400 flat rate repair where they send it in for factory diagnostics and overhaul.

[image]